# Cannot create working OpenGL 3.3 context with SDL2 on OSX 10.11 (MBP, GeForce 750M)

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, sdl-2

I have the following (working) setup code for OpenGL using SDL2:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  SDL_SetMainReady();
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) return 1);

  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_FLAG);

  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 2);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);

   auto sdl_window = SDL_CreateWindow("GL Experiment",
     SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, // x position.
     SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, // y position.
     640, // Width.
     640, // Height.
     SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
   if (sdl_window == nullptr) return 2;
   auto sdl_gl_context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(sdl_window);
   if (sdl_gl_context == nullptr) return 3;

   ...
```

However, if I change the `SDL_GL_CONTEXT_VERSION...` lines to:

```
// Use a core profile setup.
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
```

Then it breaks in an odd way:

- The program does not crash / exit with an error.
- `glClear` appears to still work (the window has whatever background colour is chosen).
- No rendering appears (I am using the [OpenGL SuperBible ‘GLTools’ code](https://github.com/ljfc/oglsuperbible5) to do the rendering, which should only be using Core Profile calls, and works with the 2.1 context)
- There are some oddities in the attributes the context reports:

  ```
  SDL_GL_RED_SIZE: 0
  SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE: 0
  SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE: 0
  SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE: 0
  SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE: 4
  SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER: 1
  SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE: 0
  SDL_GL_STENCIL_SIZE: 0
  SDL_GL_ACCUM_RED_SIZE: 0
  SDL_GL_ACCUM_GREEN_SIZE: 0
  SDL_GL_ACCUM_BLUE_SIZE: 0
  SDL_GL_ACCUM_ALPHA_SIZE: 0
  SDL_GL_STEREO: 0
  SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS: 0
  SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES: 0
  SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL: 1
  SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION: 3
  SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION: 3
  SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS: 2
  SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK: 1
  SDL_GL_SHARE_WITH_CURRENT_CONTEXT: 0
  SDL_GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB_CAPABLE: 0
  ```

So the context claims to have 0 bit colour bit depth etc. This seems inconsistent with the rendering of the initial `glClear` call though, which happily renders in colour.

I’ve checked a few OpenGL functions and they appear to resolve to real function addresses (just using OSX’s `<opengl/gl3.h>` to get these, but I’ve checked and they’re the same addresses that loading the function pointers through SDL yields.

**Update**

The output from glGetString is:

```
    GL_VENDOR: NVIDIA Corporation
    GL_RENDERER: NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M OpenGL Engine
    GL_VERSION: 4.1 NVIDIA-10.6.47 310.42.05f01
    GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION: 4.10
```

This is when 3.3/Core is requested, so clearly it gives a 4.1 context. When 2.1 is requested it’s the same but correctly shows `GL_VERSION: 2.1 ...`.

Comment: It's ok to get a 4.1 context when asking for 3.3. Have you setup a VAO?

Comment: As you say, 3.3 vs 4.1 is probably not an issue. But what about the strange buffer size values? The GLTools library is using VAOs/shaders to do its thing, yes. There may well be a bug in GLTools, and I’m investigating that too.

Comment: @Leo: Your descriptions sound exactly like you should expect context creation to behave on OSX: you only get >= 3.2 in a core profile, otherwise you'll get a legacy context limited to GL 3.2. The issue with not drawing any more in a core profile strongly indicated the use of deprecated/removed features somewhere, but what exactly is wrong is hard to guess without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Thanks @derhass, okay, that does seem most likely then. What’s confusing me though is that the drawing code itself is not written by me—it’s lifted straight from the OpenGL Superbible repository, so there really shouldn’t be any deprecated code in there. I’ve dug around a bit in their code and it’s all shaders / VBOs etc, but it’s also relatively convoluted in order to support many tutorials. I think I may ditch their approach entirely and start from scratch instead...

Comment: (Plus the reported attributes for the context seem totally whack; but then, they don’t seem to reflect what I’m observing, so it’s as likely they reflect an issue with reporting in OSX or SDL as an actual problem.)

Comment: Perhaps someone can comment on another thought: since the OGL SuperBible is pretty old, could their actual shaders be using deprecated GLSL? Would that manifest as a complete lack of rendering? (Just thinking of other places to dig here...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the OpenGL context has been created successfully, i.e. the above code works just fine in terms of creating the context.

The issue therefore appears to be twofold:

1. The OpenGL SuperBible (5th edition) drawing code must contain a bug in the form of Compatibility Profile code that prevents the actual rendering from working.
2. Either SDL 2.0.4, or the underlying OSX methods it uses, appear to contain a bug when reporting on the bit depth etc of the context created.

**Update**

Having spent some time getting the OpenGl SuperBible examples in earlier chapters working with a 3.3 Core context, I discover in a later chapter that they deliberately target a Compatibility profile so the book will work on earlier systems. This explains point 1 above, and it is a shame they do not provide this information up front when describing how to get started!

Comment: So, did you figure out why would the SDL_GL_RED_SIZE etc. still be 0? Or is there some way to render SOMETHING at least to the screen?

Comment: I never figured out why SDL was reporting incorrectly, no. I managed to get things rendering by ditching the GLTools support code from the SuperBible and just hand-rolling *everything*: shaders, VAOs etc. I'm afraid I don't remember the details, this was a while ago now.